# Alternatives to save PowerPoint slide with high resolution (300dpi) in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, microsoft-powerpoint, wine

I need to export a Power Point slide as a image (.png) with 300 dpi of resolution.

I found [this guide](http://www.motifolio.com/tips2.html) and this [microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827745) with the way to do it.

Both recommend a approach that change the `ExportBitmapResolution` registry key that will change the default resolution in Power Point.

The path of the registry is something like below:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

My problem is: I think that I can't change these keys, since I'm running the Microsoft Office Suite in Ubuntu, using Wine (actually PlayOnLinux). What should I do?

Are there any alternative?

My configuration:

> - Ubuntu 14.04
> - Microsoft Office 2012
> - PlayOnLinux 4.2.10

Comment: Have you tried just exporting it as pdf and turning that into png using the convert program of the ImageMagick package?

Comment: Well: https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/using-regedit

Comment: @GombaiSándor No, I didn't. It is possible? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thnaks for the link @TomYan.

Comment: Once you have the pdf, you can use something like this:

"   convert bridges.pdf -density 300  bridges300.png   ".

One handy feature is that you can convert a multi-page pdf and all the pages will appear as a separate png with suffixed name.

Comment: It works @GombaiSándor. Thank you! Since I was looking for alternatives, if you can send your comment as a answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad. Sure let's make it visible to anybody that would walk in the same shoe that it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ppt should be exported/saved as a pdf.

Once you have the pdf, you can use something like this:

```
convert bridges.pdf -density 300 bridges300.png
```

One handy feature is that you can convert a multi-page pdf and all the pages will appear as a separate png with suffixed name.